# html2canvas image to jsPDF renders element sizes differently between browsers

Tags: javascript, pdf, rendering, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm using `html2canvas` and `jsPDF` libraries to generate a PDF export. For lack of a better term, Safari and Chrome respectively are "seeing" the size of elements differently.
[image: Safari vs Chrome render size console messages]

Another clue is that the SVGs are oversized in Safari.

[image: SVG render difference in pdfs]

So despite having set page, window, and canvas sizes manually, the rendered sizes differ. Is there a parameter I'm missing to force resolution or something else so this behaves consistently no matter what browser runs this? (`dpi` setting doesn't appear to do anything. `scale` setting doesn't "resize", just makes img blurry if less than 1.)

```
export async function downloadPDFScorecard(printContent, fileName) {
  // const jsPDF = require('jspdf');
  console.info("download scorecard!");
  const imgWidth = 1142; 
  const pageHeight = 800;  
  const pageWidth = 1142;
  const marginY = 80;
  
  const jsPDFOpt = {
    orientation: 'l',
    unit: 'px',
    //[595.28, 841.89] is a4
    format: [pageHeight, pageWidth], 
    // putOnlyUsedFonts:true,
    compress: false,
    floatPrecision: 16 // or "smart", default is 16
   }

  const html2canvasOpt = {
    dpi: 300, // Set to 300 DPI
    scale: 1.2, // Adjusts your resolution
    width: 1142,
    height: 1256,
    windowWidth: 1142,
    windowHeight: 1256,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    logging: true,
    allowTaint: true,
    useCORS: true,
    removeContainer: true
  }

  await html2canvas(printContent, html2canvasOpt).then( (canvas) => {
      const imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
      let heightLeft = imgHeight;
      const positionX = 70;
      let positionY = 40;
      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
      var doc = new jsPDF(jsPDFOpt);
      // (inner) addImage(imageData, format, x, y, width, height, alias, compression, rotation)
      console.log("pg 1", {positionX, positionY, imgWidth, imgHeight})
      doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', positionX, positionY, imgWidth, imgHeight, 'NONE', 0);

      heightLeft -= pageHeight;
      positionY = -730;
      console.log("pg 2", {positionX, positionY, imgWidth, imgHeight})
      doc.addPage().addImage(img, 'JPEG', positionX, positionY, imgWidth, imgHeight);

      doc.save(`${fileName}.pdf`);
  });

}
```